# Error in train default object 'rf.label' not found

Tags: r

when i try to run the codes below

```
set.seed(34324)
rf.5.cv.1 <- train(rf.train.5, rf.label, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3,ntree = 1000, trControl = ctrl.1)
```

rf.label was created using this line of code

```
rf.lable <- as.factor(train$Survived)
```

Comment: Perhaps because there's a typo in the name of the variable? (`rf.label` / `rf.lable`)

Comment: hey, thanks bro i do real appreciate